# When purchasing a new laptop, which Wi-Fi standards are recommended for a college student that will be paid for by a frugal parent?

Tags: laptop, wifi, network-adapter

When purchasing a new laptop, which Wi-Fi standards are recommended for a college student that will be paid for by a frugal parent?

802.11b
802.11a
802.11g
802.11n
802.11ac
802.11ax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

802.11ac is the norm today, and that will work with everything.  If you buy a laptop and it doesn't have 802.11ac (or ax or something newer) you are getting shafted.

when 802.11ac in the future doesn't suit your needs, buy a usb-to-wifi adapter that provides you 802.11ax, or wifi6, or wifi7... etc.

Comment: Most systems these days seem to be wifi6 capable. I think the more 'important' part, would be which bands it supports - you want both 2.4 and 5 ghz support.